# Error when returning reference to type given the expression: `cond ? *this : throw()`

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++14, clang++

This appears to be an error, but I just want to confirm.  Is the following well formed?  If not, why not?

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int value;
    constexpr X(int value) : value(value) {}

    constexpr X& do_something(int x)
    {
        return x < 3 ? *this : throw("FAIL");
        //return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x(2);
    std::cout << x.do_something(1).value << std::endl;
}
```

Under `VC++2015 R3` with default solution switches, I get:

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
```

`g++ (GCC) 5.4.0` with switches `-Wall -pedantic` I get:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘X&’ from an rvalue of type ‘X’
   return x < 3 ? *this : throw("FAIL");
                                      ^
```

However, `clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)` with the switches `-Wall -pedantic` doesn't have a problem with it.

Using a `return *this;` of course doesn't have a problem.

Comment: @FredLarson, not exactly the same question, but possibly the same answer?

Comment: @Adrian Look at the [Notes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) section where the discussion of `prvalue_expression` is stated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a C++14 tag, the code is 100% well-formed C++14.

[Core issue 1560](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1560) removed the gratuitous lvalue-to-rvalue conversion here, and as a defect report resolution it should be eventually applied all the way back to the C++98/03 mode of compilers offering such a mode.

See also [GCC bug 64372](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64372).

Answer (score 3):

C++11 15/2 says:

`A try-block is a statement (Clause 6). A throw-expression is of type void...`

Then
5.16/2: (from a question that @Fred Larson Mjollnir'd and then un-duped)

> If either the second or the third operand has type void, then the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the
>   second and third operands, and one of the following shall hold:
>
> — The
>   second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression
>   (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue.
>
> — Both the second and the third operands have type
>   void; the result is of type void and is a prvalue.

So from here we see that the conditional expression operator (ternary) portion is legal. *But* the result of the `?:` is a prvalue which then cannot be legally bound to the non-const `X&` return type and is in fact ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something that's both sure to work and is easier to read instead? For example:

```
X& do_something(int x)
{
    if (x >= 3)
        throw("FAIL");

    return *this;
}
```

I'm not an expert regarding the compilers, but my guess is the example you posted will work if the compiler handles that particular corner case. The way I read this, your `do_something(int x)` function expands to this:

```
X& do_something(int x)
{
    if x < 3
        return *this;
    else
        return throw("FAIL");
}
```

Now, `throw` is a keyword and as such doesn't have a return value, so strictly speaking this is a compile-time error. However, I guess compilers (or at least some of them) are kind enough to go: *"Oh, OK... There's no return value here, but `throw` is a special situation that'll cause the function to not return, anyway, so let's not complain and let the exception handling at runtime take care of this."*

I personally don't like to take my chances with compilers and try to keep things as straight as possible, but... while that may arguably be a better practice, it may also be just a personal preference.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. The reason is that this function is actually a `constexpr`.